# Entity Framework Core pluralized model names to singular in database first

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a database where all table names are pluralized. When I generate the model from the database, the name of the classes are pluralized as well.

How can I tell EF to singularize the entity names in the code?

- EntityFrameWorkCore 3.1.2
- AspNetCore 3.1
  Database first through

`Scaffold-DbContext "connection string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context ApplicationDbContext`

Thanks

Comment: What command do you use, and which EF Core version?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ErikEJ I upated the question. I'm using .NET core 3.1 and entity framework core tools 3.1.x

Comment: @Mario Did you find any solution ?